# Переменное число аргуметов шаблона без Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

VS2010 не поддерживает Variadic Templates

мне же нужно сделать что-то вроде

```
template < typename T >
struct AgrKey
{
   T fld;
};

template < typename T, typename U >
struct AgrKey
{
   T fld;
   U fld2;
};
```

не получая при этом ошибку error C2977: 'AgrKey' : too many template arguments

как это делали до Variadic Templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать частичную специализацию с шаблонным аргументом по умолчанию

```
template < typename T, typename U = void>
struct AgrKey
{
   T fld;
   U fld2;
};

template < typename T >
struct AgrKey<T, void> 
{
   T fld;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна частичная специализация. Сначала определяете самый общий случай:

```
template <typename T, typename U = T>
struct AgrKey
{
    T fld;
    U fld2;
};
```

Потом для каждого конкретного случая делаем специализацию:

```
template <typename T>
struct AgrKey<T>
{
    T fld;
};
```

Comment: Так будет работать только когда типы разные

Comment: @Cerbo, и правда, спасибо!

Comment: с этим разобрался. 

но не могу использовать его в качестве параметра другого шаблона

template < template <typename, typename, typename> class C >
struct AgrHash

почему то работает только:
typedef AgrHash < AgrKey > A;
Но не:
typedef AgrHash < AgrKey< int, int > > A; к примеру

Comment: @haku, задайте другой вопрос